# MBProgressHud not dismissed properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

In my app which draws graphs, there are the options to send the graph as image and save the graph to photo library. But the chart may include up to 4000 data or more, so it takes time to fetch the image. Therefore I am doing that work on a separate thread and use a progress hud to indicate the activity as follows:

```
- (void)sendImageAsMail
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        // Configure HUD
        self.myHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
        self.myHUD.labelText = @"Acquiring image, please wait";
        self.myHUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        __block UIImage *graphImage;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
        ^{
            CPTGraph *currentGraph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
            graphImage = [currentGraph imageOfLayer];
            self.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(graphImage);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"mailReady" object:nil];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Cannot Send Mail" andText:@"Your mail configuration is incorrect"];
    }
}

- (void)mailReady:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailVC setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some subject here (%@)", [[[iDSConstants sharedConstants]codeTypes] objectAtIndex:_codeIndex]]];
    [mailVC setMessageBody:@"some body" isHTML:NO];
    [mailVC addAttachmentData:self.imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Design Spectrum"];

    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

    [self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now the funny thing is, the hud is not dismissed (or hidden, if you may) before presenting the mailviewcontroller; if I press cancel and dismiss the e-mail, I can see the hud spinning, and it continues to spin for few more seconds. I tried alternative approaches, such as dismissing the hud in different places of the code:

(part of the code above)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
^{
    CPTGraph *currentGraph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    graphImage = [currentGraph imageOfLayer];
    self.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(graphImage);

    **// get main thread for dismissing the hud
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });**

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"mailReady" object:nil];
});
```

but still I can see the hud where it should be hidden before. Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.